# LEFT JOIN in Google Sheets with Non-Unique Key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to join 2 arrays in Google Sheets but on a key that is not unique. Index matching and vlookups haven't been able to work. I tried an add on but I don't want to have to rely on an add-on to work 24/7. I want to be able to edit the code myself if it breaks.

**Customer List**

```
Customer ID      Category
101              Fruit
102              Fruit
103              Sweets
```

**Item List**

```
Item             Category
Apple            Fruit
Pear             Fruit
Banana           Fruit
Chocolate        Sweets
Sugar            Sweets
```

**Output Trying to Get**

```
Customer ID    Item        Category
101            Apples      Fruit
101            Pears       Fruit
101            Bananas     Fruit
102            Apples      Fruit
102            Pears       Fruit
102            Bananas     Fruit
103            Chocolate   Sweet
103            Sugar       Sweet
```

**EDIT**
Here is one thing I tried which works but is very slow and sometimes breaks:

```
function LEFTJOIN(range,range2,header) {
  var output = [];

  // checks if header
  var value;
    if(header == 1) {
      output.push(range[0]);
      value=header;
    } else if(header == "") {
      value=0;
    } else {
      value=0;
    }  
  //Duplicates array
  for(var i=0; i<range2.length; i++) {
    for(var j=value, jLen=range.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      output.push(range[j]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Then in Google Sheets I call this function in a cell but like I said its very slow.

[Google Sheets Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfyx5.png)

Comment: This is the result of a join between your two tables on the category.  Is the output you showed us what you want, and if not, then what do you want to see?

Comment: Edited it to make it more clear. That is the output I want to get.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? If you start with pseudocode, you can have a pretty good idea.

Comment: @tehhowch I haven't really tried anything because I have no idea where to begin. I wish I could look at the source god of this add on I used. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formulas-by-top-contribut/bfkbopmejhanfiegiabgnnaebndfgnji?utm_source=permalink

Comment: @JoeDemochettie a good place to start is describing in words (to yourself) the relationship between inputs and outputs, and the steps of an algorithm that will generate the output from the inputs. Once you know these steps, you can attempt to build a script that implements those steps.

Comment: @tehhowch I added some script text I was able to use. But it is still not perfect

Answer (score 0):

2 formulas would do the job:

[image]

The formula in G1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",FILTER(REPT(A2:A&"-"&B2:B&",",COUNTIF(E2:E,B2:B)),A2:A>0)),",")),"-"))
```

The formula in I1:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",1,FILTER(IF(G1:G=OFFSET(G1:G,1,),"",VLOOKUP(H:H,{UNIQUE(FILTER(E2:E,E2:E<>"")),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",FILTER(D2:D& IF(E2:E<>OFFSET(E2:E,1,),",","-"),D2:D<>"")),","))},2,)),G:G<>"")),"-"))
```

List #2 has to be sorted by category.

Comment: This does work! However, it throws out an error because the JOIN function caps out at 50000

Comment: There's another way to join: `=query(data,,2^99)`. It has no limit of 50000  chars, but need to `trim` the result.